# how do i model a pebble like sink

Tags: modeling, bevel

i want to model a sink like the goal attached below. [image: goal]
the top surface always seems to be flat, how do i get it to bulge like the target sink?[image]
so here was my approach

1. added a cylinder and loop cut in middle
2. scaled and beveled the edge to make it bulgy
   3)added an UV sphere and then subtracted it from the cylinder using boolean modifier

Comment: You should remove the top faces, select the 2 edge loops and Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops, you should also remove half of the vertical and horizontal edge loops to make it easier to model, then scale down the top edge loop so that it comes close to the shape

Answer (score 0):

You should work with less faces, it would make things easier. You could begin with a 16/8 sphere, flatten it on Z:

[image]

Cut its top:

[image]

Extrude down its inner edge loop:

[image]

Extrude again and scale until you get the inner shape:

[image]

Bevel some edge loops in order to have a more accurate outer shape, etc:

[image]

Also slightly bevel the edge loops that you want to keep sharp:

[image]

Comment: your solution is perfect but if you look at the reference image, the cavity is bit skewed towards one side, how would that be achievable?

Comment: Yes you need to rotate the bottom, move some edges, etc